# i would like to install an application but the terminal does not allow to put the password

Tags: password

I would like to install Microsoft office. I read the procedure online and I tried to follow it, but when I open the terminal, it doesn't allow me to put my password. How can I fix this problem? Thank you
[image]

Comment: It's reading your password. It's just not echoing your password to the screen. Type your password normally and hit <ENTER>. This type of password security feature is many decades old.

Answer (score 0):

When it asks you the password , enter it then press Enter, it will read it without print the password or any ****